# How to open upi apps from a MEAN app running on ios device with this link "upi://pay?pa=${upiId}&pn=%20&tr=%20&am=${amount}&cu=INR" working on android

Tags: android, ios, mean-stack, payment, upi

I was able to open UPI apps in my android when I click the pay now button. But in ios its not working. How to implement the same in ios?

I tried opening the link in ios but instead of showing the UPI apps it opens whatsApp UPI payment by default.